# Places AutoComplete Fragment Closes Automatically

Tags: android, android-studio, google-places

I am implementing google places api in my android app. I open the google auto complete textview, and i try to type. Once I started typing the fragment closes automatically. I used both the intent and listener but both are giving the same problem. here is the code:

Code for Listener:

```
autocompleteSupportFragment.setPlaceFields(Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME));
autocompleteSupportFragment.setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.CITIES);
autocompleteSupportFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
           @Override
           public void onPlaceSelected(@NonNull Place place) {
               Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+place.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(@NonNull Status status) {

           }
       });
```

Code for Intent

```
 lc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
                        AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, fields)
                        .build(getContext());
                startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });

 @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Place place = Autocomplete.getPlaceFromIntent(data);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+place.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (resultCode == AutocompleteActivity.RESULT_ERROR) {
                // TODO: Handle the error.
                Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
                Log.i(TAG, status.getStatusMessage());
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // The user canceled the operation.
            }

        }

    }
```

Code for layout:

```
<fragment
                android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment1"
                android:name="com.google.android.libraries.places.widget.AutocompleteSupportFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10sp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

I saw other solutions but it was not helpfull. What changes should i have. I have enabled google places in the console as well.

Comment: Its always better to add complete activity code.

Comment: Facing same problem. Any solutions?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a solution, however, I may provide a way to help troubleshoot this issue.

In the `onActivityResult` method put this Log :

```
Status status = Autocomplete.getStatusFromIntent(data);
Log.e("SomeTagToFilterTheLogcat", status.toString());
```

And then see the output to determine the error.
Mine was that billing was not enabled though my google console account says otherwise, maybe because I am using the free tier with an old account where GCP was not requiring any credit cards.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the project is not authorized to use API key you are trying to use.

try using the link from the `google_maps_api.xml` file which is generated for you automatically when you use the wizard.

It has the format

`https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=SHA1KEY;packagename&pli=1`

example: if your package is `com.example.myapplication` and your SHA-1 key is `61:DB:7B:CB:A9:86:62:51:CF:88:9E:AC:ED:PC:E8:2E:CB:C6:43:60`

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=61:DB:7B:CB:A9:86:62:51:CF:88:9E:AC:ED:PC:E8:2E:CB:C6:43:60;com.example.myapplication&pli=1

Comment: The api key is aldready generated and working properly. The places api fragment closes on typing.

Answer (score 1):

There's an additional configuration that you have to add in the google maps API

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: please use English for screenshots

Answer (score 0):

you should log your status in onError method to know the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You should initialize like this:

```
if (!Places.isInitialized()) {
   Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "Your_Api_Key");
}
PlacesClient placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
```

Comment: Still on typing the fragment is closing on its own

Comment: My problem solved this way. I edited can you try again.

Comment: Still not working. I am using this in a fragment. What is the reason

Comment: I have enabled places api as well.

Comment: I have enabled places api. Is there anything else i have to enable?

Comment: No, Map api and Places api is enough.

Comment: An error occurred: Status{statusCode=You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started, resolution=null} this is the error i am getting. But i aldready enabled billing.

Comment: Maybe, your project is not linked to a billing account. Check this. – Kasım Özdemir 6 mins ago    Delete

Comment: It is connected to a billing account

Comment: need to connect with  billing account is necessary?